# Accessing sub-element of a list

Tags: python

For a list of words, how can I access each alphabet of the word. For example

```
food = ['eel', 'egg', 'yam', 'nut', 'oats']
```

I need to retrieve each food by its individual letters and make it into a list, i.e.

```
each_food[1] = ['e', 'e', 'l']
each_food[2] = ['e', 'g', 'g']
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `print(list("eel"))` should give you an idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list(<string>)
```

will split a string into a list of characters

```
food = ['eel', 'egg', 'yam', 'nut', 'oats']

print(list(food[0]))
print(list(food[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to store the lists in an array named `each_food`, you can use a for loop to split the string into a list of individual characters and then append each list of characters to `each_food`:

```
food = ['eel', 'egg', 'yam', 'nut', 'oats']    
each_food = []

for item in food:
    each_food.append(list(item))
```

This way you can access each list of characters with the corresponding string index (starting from 0). For example:

```
each_food[0]
```

Would produce the first list as output:

```
['e', 'e', 'l']
```